# css issues on the website for displaying the products

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am working on the following website, as per the website homepage is running good, only problem is: the images which comes in the section of this image should show 4 in a row, but the css is not doing so and if i force it to float: left, the hover effect only works on the first four products only and not on all.

here is the website link http://sinaimarble.com/beta/?init=1

here is the screenshot of what portion of the page I am talking about

[image]

this is the loom video, i added the float but the hover effect worked on 1st row only and not on second rows and after

```
https://www.useloom.com/share/55327cbb265743f39c2c442c029277e0
```

Comment: change width `24.98%` to `23.98%` and put `display:inline-block` in `.project-post` class

Comment: you can use `24.84%` for exact image fit in screen, in `23.98%` there should be some white space after 4th image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution helpful to you.

change the css of the `project-post` class.

Use this css.

```
.masonry.four-col .project-post {
    width: 24.84%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this solution is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.masonry.four-col .project-post {
    width: 24.98%;
    float: left;
}
```